# Is Java runtime pre-installed on MAC OSX?

Tags: java, macos, jnlp, java-web-start

I need to port a java desktop app for mac os-x. 
The app will be launched via JNLP. 
Is the Java runtime environment pre-installed on MAC-OSX ?

Comment: Use the [`deployJava.js`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html) script to write the link to the JNLP.  If the right minimum version of Java is not installed (and there is a version available) it will guide the user through installing it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general.  Java 5 or Java 6 was preinstalled on Mac OS X up to [10.6](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH6928), but this ceased in 10.7.

Besides, a recent Mac OSX update uninstalls the version of Java 6 plugin previously supported by Apple.  Apple have never supported Java 7.

https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/apple_s_java_mac_os

You (or your users) need to download and install Java 7 for the Mac from Oracle.  But @Andrew Thompson's comment (see above) offers a good way to smooth that "speed bump".

Comment: The update does not uninstall Java 6.  It uninstalls the applet plugin from all of your web browsers, and the webstart functionality needed to launch jnlp files, and a few other things.  Java 6 remains on your system if it was installed.